# How to slice a string into sub strings of words and append to list recursively?

Tags: python

I am trying to slice a string based on the limit provide and append the slices to a list if they form an entire word.
If they do not form a complete word, i want to go forward/back till the point I find the previous words end and then slice the string at that point and continue this for the rest of the string.

I have written the code but having problems doing it in a recursive way.

```
strr = "stackoverflow is the best knowledge platform"
limit = 11

def get_list(strr, limit, fin_list = []):
    i = 0
    if limit <= len(strr):
        if strr[limit].isspace(): 
            fin_list.append(strr[i:limit])
            i=limit+1
            return get_list(strr[i:],limit, fin_list)
            print(fin_list)
        else:
            return get_list(strr,limit-1)


print(get_list(strr, limit))
```

My limit is 11 so my expected output is

```
['stackoverflow','is the best','knowledge','platform']
```

stackoverflow ==> complete word hence move forward

Another method I tried was using dictionaries but it did not solve the problem.
can this be achieve in a typical python style one line of code using comprehension?

Comment: "to slice a string based on the limit" - `limit` is length in symbols? You need to split by words but only if length of words exceed `limit`?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are not trying to implement [NLTK sentence tokenizing](https://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-ii-sentence-tokenize-and-word-tokenize)?

Comment: why recursive? the easiest solution leads to iterating over your string once to split it...

Comment: the limit specifies the  number of characters that my substring can have. for e.g. if the limit = 3 then the output would look like: ['stackoverflow','is','the','best','knowledge','platform'] and if limit is say 100 then ['stackoverflow is the best platform']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop to find the closest white space to the limit, going backwards, and if no white space is found, then go forward. Recursively find the next substring until the remaining string fits the length limit:

```
def get_list(strr, limit):
    if len(strr) <= limit:
        return [strr] if strr else []
    i = limit
    while 0 < i < len(strr) and not strr[i].isspace():
        i -= 1
    if not i:
        i = limit
        while i < len(strr) and not strr[i].isspace():
            i += 1
    return [strr[:i]] + get_list(strr[i + 1:], limit)
```

so that:

```
get_list('stackoverflow is the best knowledge platform', 11)
```

returns:

```
['stackoverflow', 'is the best', 'knowledge', 'platform']
```

Alternatively, you can split the input by white space, and iterate over the list of words to decide whether to add a word to the current string of words or to output the current string of words and start a new one based on whether the new word is going to make the string of words exceed the limit:

```
def get_list(strr, limit):
    words = ''
    for word in strr.split():
        if len(words) + len(word) + 1 > limit:
            if words:
                yield words
                words = word
            else:
                yield word
                words = ''
        else:
            if words:
                words += ' '
            words += word
    if words:
        yield words
```

so that:

```
print(list(get_list(strr, 3)))
print(list(get_list(strr, 11)))
print(list(get_list(strr, 100)))
```

outputs:

```
['stackoverflow', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'knowledge', 'platform']
['stackoverflow', 'is the best', 'knowledge', 'platform']
['stackoverflow is the best knowledge platform']
```